# usage of separable and inseparable words

Tags: orthography, compounds

Words like

> wheelbarrow

and

> nailbrush

are used mingled, the ***wheel*** goes with ***barrow*** in inseparable form.

On the other hand, words like

> tank top

and

> high heels

as it sounds written separable.

1. On what reasons they're written like this?
2. Is there a clear way to distinguish the correct form and making them in
   writing?

Comment: "Wheelbarrow" *is* one word.  "Nailbrush" is apparently recognized by some dictionaries, but is not commonly used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to tell: Look in the dictionary.  I'm not trying to be glib.  I look in the dictionary *all the time* to check to see if something is two words or a single compound word.  In fact, earlier today I couldn't remember if "more so" was one word like "notwithstanding."  It's not, but to be sure, I had to check.

Anyway, there is no set pattern you can fall back on to tell.  Even the same word goes many different ways: halftime, half-day, half past.  All three refer to time; all three combine "half" differently. Often, the same construction deviates from itself: mid-twenties and late twenties.  This makes the phrase "mid- to late twenties" an awkward construction.  The long and the short of it is it's without rhyme or reason, so you either have to try and remember it all or keep a dictionary handy—or more likely, both.